# add tab bar to tab panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to add tab bar to my tab panel,
I added tab panel to my fiddle, but not sure how to add tab bar
can you tell me how to add tab bar to that tab panel

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        title: 'Foo'
    }, {
        title: 'Bar',
        tabConfig: {
            title: 'Custom Title',
            tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, there is a tab bar: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tkm

Comment: You should be able to do it with this example of ExtJS Kitchen Sink: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#advanced-tabs